# My gameobjects doesnt collide in unity 2d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've two gameobejects(a duck and a knife) and each of them has a rigidbody and a box colider.It will be a 2D game for android. I looked on other questions and tried many different stuff but none of them worked.

The Following code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

                 Debug.Log("Bullet hit23!");
         }
```

I hope somebody can help me :=)

edit:

I addded a is trigger, and I noticed that only a duck can collide with a duck and not with the knife

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing 2D game, That means you are using Rigidbody2D and Collider2D for your game objects. If not, then attach your duck and knife objects BoxCollider2D and Rigidbody2D. Finally change that code to 2D version of it.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
   Debug.Log("Bullet hit23!");
}
```

This must be the solution for you.